# Why isn't my subscription adding data to Meteor.user()?

Tags: meteor

I'm publishing this user information (as a test FYI, not going to reveal all this information in production)

```
Meteor.publish('user.private', function userPrivate() {
  if (!this.userId) {
    return this.ready();
  }

  return Meteor.users.find({
    _id: this.userId
  }, {
    fields: {
      'services.microsoft': 1,
      'services.google': 1
    }
  });
});
```

I'm subscribing like this:

```
Template.App_body.onCreated(function appBodyOnCreated() {
  this.subscribe('user.private');
});
```

I've confirmed that this exact query works and returns data using `meteor mongo`, yet this information does not appear in the `Meteor.user()` call on the client. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the publication name to null to make it automatically publish.

```
Meteor.publish(null, function () {
  return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, {
    fields: { /** ... fields here */ }
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify how/why this works? And when you say automatically publish, do I still need a subscribe call?

Comment: Nah, you don't need to subscribe, it should be automatic if set to "null". the null value essentially means "publish this, no matter what".